# FacetSearchListener implementation details

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement whereby I want to hide a product on the front end based on the product attribute.I am trying to implement `FacetSearchListener`, but I am stuck up as to how should I start.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more. hide product on PLP / PDP? on which condition? hide to specific customer group or for all customers?

Comment: Have you tried to use rule engine? Maybe you can use any of source template defined in rule engine. Or You can also set product visibility via using Category Visibility options of the product group to set visibility of customer groups.

Comment: @HybrisFreelance,I did not get a chance to test but for now for restricting it for all,I have written a code like :      ctx.getSearchQuery().addFliter("productAttribute","value");.Should it work,and will it reuqire the "productAttribute" to be indexed?